# Unable to connect node manager through WLST

Tags: weblogic12c, wlst

While trying to connect node manager via WLST, I'm getting the following error.

```
Connecting to Node Manager ...
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
  File "<iostream>", line 111, in nmConnect
  File "<iostream>", line 553, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error occurred while performing nmConnect : Cannot connect to Nod
e Manager. : Connection refused: connect. Could not connect to NodeManager. Chec
k that it is running at /***.***.**.**:5556.
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace :
```

Node Manager is currently running as Windows Service and 3 managed servers within a cluster are managed via this node manager. 
Can anyone please help me to connect node manager via WLST? What might be the possible errors?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please share the command how you are executed nmConnect(). Also share is it a plain/SSL based nodemanager. confirm that ip address and 5556 is running or not using telnet command. Check jps -l command to check nodemanager running or not.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that Nodemanager is down. Therefore, start your Nodemanager.